# PHP MySQL JS AJAX - Loop issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loops

I have PHP loop. I take the id, lat, lon data from record, passed it to script to do some calculations, then I passed this data to AJAX which will save the results of that calculation in MySQL DB, if it's successful then it will add the line of confirmation text to a results div.

My Code (I did trim it to keep focus on the issue)

```
<div id="distance_results"></div>

<?php
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test")
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $id = $row['id'];   
        $city = $row['city'];   
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lon = $row['lon'];
        $driving_from = "51.528308,-0.3817765";
        $driving_to = "$lat,$lon";
?>
<script>
    var id = '<?php echo $id ?>';
    var city = '<?php echo $city ?>';
    var start = '<?php echo $driving_from ?>';
    var end = '<?php echo $driving_to ?>';

   // code
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    // code
    var mi = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;

            console.log(id);
            console.log(city);
            console.log(mi);

//Ajax Begin
            $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'test-dc-upd.php',
            data: {'updateid': id, 'distance': mi},
            success: function() { 

            html="Distance between London and " + city  + " is " + mi;
            $("#distance_results").append("<p>"+html+"</p>");

                }
            });
 //Ajax End

} else {}

});  


</script>


<?php } ?>
```

AND CODE FOR "test-dc-upd.php"

```
$id = $_POST['updateid'];
$distance = $_POST['distance'];
$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE test SET distance='$distance' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
```

So PHP is looping thru MySQL DB, when but when I look at console:

'mi' values are calculated well according to lat / lon;

PROBLEMS:

1) 'id' and 'city' values stay the same (values of last record in the loop);

2) AJAX is updating value of last record in the loop only

So it obvious there is a some issue with the loop.

Any suggestion to what i do wrong?

Comment: Change $("<p>"+ html +"</p>").append("#distance_results"); to $("#distance_results").append("<P>"+html+"</p>");

Comment: ok progress is displaing now, but the biggest problem is still there (values of variables are the same, and ajax updating of these records)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it a little different way i was hoping for ( But distance and travel time has been calculate for more then 3000 locations).

So what i did is to make sure mysql (test-dc.php) finds record where distance and travel time has not been calculated, makes calculation, update record with Ajax. Ajax on succesion opens the (test-dc.php) again, And is looping thru all results till there is nothing else to calculate. Had to refesh few times but thats fine, job done.

Adjustment to Mysql query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE distance='' LIMIT 1")
```

and to AJAX:

```
success: function() { 
   html="Distance between London and " + city  + " is " + mi;
   $("#distance_results").append("<p>"+html+"</p>");
   location.href = "test-dc.php"
}
```

So that did the trick, but i still belive there is a better way of achiving the same result, i will be happy if someone  could help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Change this 
`$("<p>"+ html +"</p>").append("#distance_results");`
To

```
$("#distance_results").append("<p>"+ html +"</p>");
```

Your jquery code is wrong. First you have to put selector and in append function the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Nita, change the success function from:

```
success: function() { 

    html="Distance between CITYX and " + city  + " is " + mi;
    $("<p>"+ html +"</p>").append("#distance_results");  

    }
});
```

To

```
success: function() {
        html="Distance between CITYX and " + city  + " is " + mi;
        $("#distance_results").append(<p>"+ html +"</p>);
        // this will append the dynamic content to #distance_results
    }
});
```

Explanation:

> To put a dynamic content is some html object you have to first prepare
>   the content than select the html object and put the content into it.

Answer (score 0):

In a loop calling ajax request is not a good practice we can easily pass array of values to javascript using the function implode like this

this implode function is for single dimensional array,

```
 var ar = <?php echo '["' . implode('", "', $ar) . '"]' ?>;
```

For your question you need to create a multi dimensional array for the result like this ..

```
<?php
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM test");
    $arr= array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
   $arr[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'city'=>$row['city],'lat'=>$row['lat']...etc);
}
  ?>
```

afetr that you can pass each item in the array to javascript like this

```
var idArray= <?php echo '["' . implode(', ', array_column($arr, 'id')); . '"]' ?>;
   var cityArray= <?php echo '["' . implode(', ', array_column($arr, 'city')); . '"]' ?>;
```

you can get each tag as array in javascript after that using a sing ajax request pass all javascript array to php script. and manipulate in the server side .

Your ajax request is like this

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test-dc-upd.php',
        data: {
          'idArray':idArray,
          'cityArray':cityArray, //etc you need pass all array like this 
        },
        success: function(data) { 

            // your success code goes here

            }
        });
```

> Note that  array_column() function only supported by php 5.3 or above

Comment: hmm that seem more professional, but i need to make a calculation of distance first, then send it to AJAX?? I updated my question with content of "test-dc-upd.php". Cause this file will have to be altered too...

Comment: so my question would be here how do i put results od distance calculation into array, and then how do I udated that value in Mysql for each ID?

Comment: in your code you are finding distance by this function right ? directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) , then the parameter request  is coming from where ?? @Nita

Comment: Thank you your help, I found the soultion, different than yours, but i have one question about your soultion? what hapens if i have 3000 recers? or even better yest what happens if i have 36000 records?

Comment: from my answer point of view my intention is u to think like that , it's a kind path to the solution, if you have a bigamount of records then you need to process the data and store it an array and pass to the server via ajax . in your way the number of ajax request is big , that is not a good practice